# What's the difference between a Key Derivation Function and a Password-Hash?

Tags: hash, key-derivation

It seems to me that anything that was sufficiently good as a KDF would work just fine as a password hash, though the reverse might not be true.  Are there considerations specific to password-hashing that don't apply to KDFs?

To clarify: This is about key-stretching KDFs.  Not the kind for diversifying keys (eg. HKDF)